# Opensuse: analog of apt-file?

Tags: opensuse

I want to search a file name, cnf as I know search only binaries.
For example, I want to search all packages which contain "usr/include"

On Debian

```
apt-file search usr/include
```

On Fedora/Rocky

```
dnf provides /usr/include
```

On Opensuse?

Comment: Is `zypper search --provides  /usr/include` or `zypper search --provides --match-exact  /usr/include` what you want?

Comment: Yes it works, add as an answer so I can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```bash
zypper search --provides  /usr/include
#or
zypper search --provides --match-exact  /usr/include
```

From `zypper search --help`:

> --provides
>
> > Search for packages which provide the search strings.

Also from that same output you can see several options that may be given to `zypper search`, e.g:

```
--match-substrings      Search for a match to partial words (default).
--match-words           Search for a match to whole words only.
-x, --match-exact       Searches for an exact match of the search strings.
```